# What is the purpose of this `data[0]` declaration in struct?

Tags: c, arrays, structure, c99

In the C, syntax of **flexible array member** like this:

```
struct s 
{ 
    int n; 
    double d[];  // flexible array member
};
```

And, **Zero size array** illegal in C.

If I declare array like this:

```
struct s 
{ 
    double d[0];  // Zero size array
};
```

GCC give warning:

```
warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array 'd' [-Wpedantic]
```

So, I'm going to my main question.

I saw following code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/squashfs/squashfs_fs.h#L435).

```
struct squashfs_xattr_entry {
    __le16          type;
    __le16          size;
    char            data[0];
};
```

In C zero-size array illegal.

Then,

- What is the purpose of this `data[0]` declaration in struct?
- What does `data[0]` do here?

Comment: @chux Specifically GNU GCC and Clang. M$VC rejects zero-length arrays, however.

Comment: So you didn't even google about how many dozen duplicates there are?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to C99 (the ISO standard version of C released in 1999) the only way to implement a flexible array member was if the compiler supported it as an extension. GCC supported it by using a static length of `0`, hence `foo buffer[0]`.

C99 made it legal, but they decided to prescribe the syntax `foo buffer[]` instead of retaining GCC's `[0]` version.

GCC still supports `buffer[0]` for compatibility with code written before C99.

This is explained in GCC's documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Zero-Length.html (emphasis mine):

> Zero-length arrays **are allowed in GNU C**

Note that "GNU C" (the GCC implementation of C) has its own extensions on-top of ISO C.

Comment: Yes. GCC accepts not only `-std=c99`, but also `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: How many times does this question need to be answered?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGBhQbmPwH8 ;)